# How to pass -X options programmatically to the java compiler

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac

[JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) - How to pass `-X options` programmatically to the JavaCompiler class?

Comment: Which options are you attempting to pass? Verify you are not passing options intended for the JVM when executing and not the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JavaCompiler](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/tools/JavaCompiler.html) page you linked to has some nice examples. They invoke the compiler with the following line of code:

```
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null, null, null, compilationUnits1).call();
```

The fourth argument to the `getTask` method is a list of option strings (really `Iterable<String>` but a list will be sufficient). So you can do:

```
compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, null,
    Arrays.asList("-Xlint:all"),
    null, compilationUnits1).call();
```

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK The Java Compiler is runs in the current JVM. If you want to set a `-X` option you need to set it for your program.

Comment: I was intending to pass -Xlint for a certain files to be compiled and other flags for other files. Just need the flexibility in passing flags per file.